# ASP.NET Web Api Swagger string parameters error - no description

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger-ui, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I am using Swagger UI to test my ASP.NET Web Api app. I added a class to allow operation parameters

```
public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
{
    if (operation.Parameters == null) 
        operation.Parameters = new List<OpenApiParameter>();

    operation.Parameters.Add(new OpenApiParameter
    {
        Name = "ApiKey",
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Required = true,
        Schema = new OpenApiSchema
        {
            Type = "String"
        }
    });
    operation.Parameters.Add(new OpenApiParameter
    {
        Name = "Authentication",
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Required = false,
        Schema = new OpenApiSchema
        {
            Type = "String"
        }
    });
}
```

In my Startup.cs, I added this line to the ConfigurationServices method

```
c.OperationFilter<CustomHeaderSwaggerAttribute>();
```

When I try and test one of the controller methods, my ApiKey string parameter always show an error no matter what I put in the textbox.

[image]

Comment: This probably isn't the answer but would be quick to test. Have you tried: `Type = "string"` with a lowercase S?

Comment: @SBFrancies create and answer for me to mark. Changing "String" to "string" worked!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the `Schema` property but the following worked for me in past (setting the `type` to `string`):

```
operation.Parameters.Add(new Parameter
        {
            name = "ApiKey",
            @in = ParameterLocation.Header,
            required = true,
            type = "string"                
        });
```

For more details, refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62798308/1875256)